# Vaadin don't call getSystemMessages when out of sync

Tags: spring, error-handling, synchronization, vaadin

I want to customize the Out of sync message like here: https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/application.errors.html

I have:

```
public class SpringApplicationServlet extends AbstractApplicationServlet {
...
@Override
protected SystemMessages getSystemMessages() {
  logger.debug("getSystemMessages()");
  CustomizedSystemMessages m = new CustomizedSystemMessages();
  m.setOutOfSyncCaption("My custom caption");
  return m;
}
...
```

I clearly see that getSystemMessages() is not called, but red notification with caption "Out of sync" is showed when working with multiple windows.
The book of Vaadin says

> You can override the default system messages by implementing the 
>   getSystemMessages() method in the UI class.

How can I know in which class to override `getSystemMessages()`? `SpringApplicationServlet` seemed to be the most suitable

Answer (score 0):

According to https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/Application.html#getSystemMessages
that method should be implemented in a class extending `Application`

So now it works:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
...
  @Override
  public static SystemMessages getSystemMessages() {
  ...
```

Although Java does not allow overriding static method, Vaadin makes an exception and calls this method if present.